# Assign Credits between different member types

Tags: zoo-visitor, devdemon

Im a EE newbie and looking to use zoo visitor and credits as badge system to users.  How I want it to work is Member Group A is able to assign credits to Member Group B so lets say a teacher is able to assign credits to students so their is two kinds of member groups.

I would create two types of dashboards for the member group and the Group A could award any member in Group B.

Is this possible with Credits?

Sorry for the repetition up there!

Best,
Mario